# How can I reapply to a job I resigned from after a very short time

Tags: communication

I had been hired by a company and during my training period I got a better job offer so I resigned after 1 week. I am no longer working for the other company and I believe the original company is hiring for a similar position. How would I go about reapplying?

Comment: Don't **re**-apply. You don't want them to remember how unreliable you were.

Comment: @keshlam I agree.  She's permanently marked as a flake at that job.  I would never rehire anyone that quit after a week.

Comment: You just apply.  Likely they will trash the application but you are no worse off then if you did not apply.

Comment: How long ago were you part of this company?  If it's anything past a year ago, they likely forgot who you are.

Answer (score 3):

As others have already commented, don't waste your time applying to that company. By quitting after a week, you said to them "I'm not interested in working here, it's just something to fill in the time until I find a 'better' job." They'll very reasonably take the position that you'll just do the same thing again the next time a 'better' job comes along, so it's not worth the time and expense of hiring you.

You made a decision to burn the company's goodwill by quitting after a week; actions have consequences and in this case one of the consequences is that you'll probably never work for that company in the future.